# Getting a null/zero values for passed parameters and not being updated after locally assigned

Tags: c#, winforms

It seems that I am getting a null/zero for my passed param n&m and their values are not updated in AHPmodel class after being assigned locally!

```
{

        public partial class Weighing_Factors_Pairwise : Form
            {
                private Form4 frm4;

                public static int n { get; private set; }
                public static int m { get; private set; }

                AHPModel model = new AHPModel(n,m);

                public Weighing_Factors_Pairwise(Form4 frm4)
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    this.frm4 = frm4;
                    n = frm4.checkbox.Count;
                    m = frm4.checksys.Count;
                }

                public AHPModel(int n, int m)
                {
                    superDim = n * m;
                    nCriteria = n;
                    mChoices = m;                }
                }

                private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {      
                        model.CalculateModel();
                        GeneralMatrix calcCriteria = model.CalculatedCriteria;
                        GeneralMatrix results = model.ModelResult;
                        GeneralMatrix choices = model.CalculatedChoices;
                }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile, and it's definitely not a [mcve]. Also where and how are you checking for updated `n` and `m` values? And the only place where you are assigning them is in the `Weighing_Factors_Pairwise` constructor

Comment: I thought the getters and setters will update them. Now it works by locally passing the instance's values.

Comment: Is this a challenge where the one who breaks most conventions gets the cookie? This looks horrible. Try static code analysis (Visual Studio) or Resharper or some other automated way to help you see where you deviate from "good code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you first Create an instance of AHPModel where n, m are both null. you should make some replacement in order of your statements, try this one:

```
            AHPModel model; 
            public Weighing_Factors_Pairwise(Form4 frm4)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.frm4 = frm4;

                n = frm4.checkbox.Count;
                m = frm4.checksys.Count;
                APModel = new AHPModel(n,m);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @MohsenCs. It works now like a charm :)